# Looking for a better JavaScript/CSS switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of `JavaScript/JQuery` code that I have been tweaking in order to have a `webpage` switch `CSS` `scripts` if the page is resized too small, or if it starts up too small.

The resize seems to work great, but I think i may be cheating on the `window.onload` statement to make the resize check happen. I can see it when I start to load the page and see it have to "think" before switching to the `narrow.css`.

I am looking for suggestions on how to make this bit of code preform better, or be less taxing on a `mobile` connection.

```js
"use strict";

var windowsize = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {
  windowsize = $(window).width();

  if (windowsize < 600) {
    document.getElementById("myCSS").setAttribute("href", "css/narrow.css");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myCSS").setAttribute("href", "css/mystyles.css");
  }
});

//force window size check at load to kick in if statement
window.onload = $(window).resize();
```

Comment: You should use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) instead

Comment: Your approach isn't bad, if you were targeting browsers that didn't support media queries, but as you can see is every browser except IE8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries does.

Answer (score 4):

css media queries are designed for this purpose: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

To apply this approach with the details in your example you might do something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /*CSS from css/narrow.css*/
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  /*CSS from css/mystyles.css*/
}
```

Comment: I have marked myself a ToDo to switch this over to a CSS3 solution once I am done with my JavaScript training. Until then, I have removed the onload as suggested. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

1. It is probably best to have `#myCSS` set originally to the mobile stylesheet, and if the screen is too big, switch to the desktop stylesheet.
2. No need to wait for the `load` event to execute; if the JS snippet is after `#myCSS`, then `#myCSS` is already in the DOM, and one can just write `$(window).resize();` without `window.onload =`. This should prevent the browser from waiting till everything else is loaded before loading the stylesheet.